# Error while Scrapping messages from a Telegram group

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, telegram-api

I am using following code for scrapping messages from a telegram group but getting error;
Please guide me how to solve this or suggest any-other efficient solution.

> RuntimeError: You must use "async with" if the event loop is running (i.e. you are inside an "async def")

Code:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import datetime
import pandas as pd


import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("telethon.config")

api_id = config["telethon_credentials"]["api_id"]
api_hash = config["telethon_credentials"]["api_hash"]

chats = ['cryptodubai7']


client =  TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash)


df = pd.DataFrame()


for chat in chats:
    with TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        for message in client.iter_messages(chat, offset_date=datetime.date.today() , reverse=True):
            print(message)
            data = { "group" : chat, "sender" : message.sender_id, "text" : message.text, "date" : message.date}

            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1])
            df = df.append(temp_df)

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are creating 2 `TelegramClient`'s, doesn't seem needed
- You need to `client.start()`
- Like the error suggest, you need to use `async`
- Also an `await` is needed for retrieving the messages
- I'd recommend using an event loop, like `asyncio`

Something like this should get you in the right direction:
<sub>Untested!</sub>

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import asyncio

import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("telethon.config")

api_id = config["telethon_credentials"]["api_id"]
api_hash = config["telethon_credentials"]["api_hash"]

chats = ['cryptodubai7']

client =  TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

async def main():

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for chat in chats:
        
        messages = await client.iter_messages(chat, offset_date=datetime.date.today() , reverse=True)
        for message in messages:
            print(message)
            data = { "group" : chat, "sender" : message.sender_id, "text" : message.text, "date" : message.date}

            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1])
            df = df.append(temp_df)

    df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_localize(None)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```